# How to prove iff statement involving simultaneous equations

Tags: proof-writing, systems-of-equations

I'm working through some proof questions when I got completely stumped by this question. I do not know how or where to start this question. So any help is greatly appreciated!

> Prove that the simultaneous equations $Ax+By+E=0$ and $Cx+Dy+F=0$ have exactly one solution if and only if $AD-BC \neq 0$

Comment: The equations of $Ax + By + E = 0$ and $Cx + Dy + F = 0$ are $2$ linear equations in $2$ unknowns. Do you know how to work with them to try to determine what value(s), if any, $x$ and $y$ may be in terms of the coefficients?

Comment: If instead I gave you numbers $A=1$, $B=2$, $E=3$, $C=4$, $D=5$, $F=6$, what would you do to find the solution set? Now do the same thing without knowing the numbers.

Comment: @JohnOmielan No, I wasn't aware that you would be able to determine that. This part of proofs involving simultaneous equations has completely confused me.

Comment: @spuddy As Lee Mosher suggested, you handle it similarly to the case where you had specific numbers, but use symbols instead. For example, you can eliminate $x$ from the equations through multiplying the first one by $C$ and subtracting the second one multiplied by $A$. Do you see how this works & how to possibly continue from there?

Comment: Ok, so I've gotten up to $(AD-BC)y=EC-AF$ which I think proves the forward assumption from there because $EC-AF \neq 0 \therefore AD-BC \neq 0$. How do I prove the reverse? (i.e. if $AD-BC \neq 0$ then there is only one solution)